# Write array in a php file

Tags: php, arrays, fopen

I have this function:

```
function update_config($config)
        { 
         $buffer         = array();
         $buffer[]       = '<?php';
         foreach( $config as $key => $value ) {
                $buffer[]   = '$config[\'' .$key. '\'] = \'' .str_replace('\'', '&#039;', $value). '\';';
         }
         $buffer[]       = '?>';
            
            $data           = implode("\n", $buffer);
            $path           = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'settings.php';
        
            $fp = fopen($path, 'wb');
            if ($fp) {
                flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
                $len = strlen($data);
                fwrite($fp, $data, $len);
                flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
                fclose($fp);
            }
         }
```

is working very well, it insert like this `$config[title] = 'Demo title';`

How I can make to don't overwrite all file when I change something?
Exemple, if I have 3 entries in settings.php and when I want to insert another, file is totaly rewrited with new insert only!

And I want when some exist like $config[title] change only value!

Thank you!

Comment: I'd use some structured data format for saving config - such as XML, JSON, YAML etc. Then You'll be able to load the complete data structure from file, make necessary changes and save it complete again.

Comment: I can't save complet, will be updated from many places!

Comment: Use a database for gods sake..

Comment: I don't want to make request to database every time when I need info

Comment: Why? You think file I/O is faster?

Comment: You can use some sort of in-memory database, if i/o speed is a concern.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz if it's a PHP file that gets included, it will actually be op-code cached in memory. It doesn't get much faster than that.

Comment: What is caching good for, if you make constant changes to this file?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz well, in this case it's free and doesn't do any harm. Adding a database or in-memory store is outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2):

With a little extra additions, [`var_export()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) will help you do what you're looking to. It accepts any PHP variable and will export it to a parsable representation.

Generally you would want to load the full config array, modify only desired values, and re-write the full array back to file.

You can do so like this:

```php
$config = [
    "myValue1" => 10,
    "myValue2" => "Hello, world"
];

$configCode = '<?php $config = ' . var_export($config, true) . ';';

file_put_contents("config.inc.php", $configCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

better way is to save your config as a json file. then you can read all content into an array, change some variables and write the new one to the file.

```
{
  "title": "hello",
  "name": "test",
  "bla": "muh"
}
```

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents('config.json');
$config = json_decode($string, TRUE);
$config['title'] = "new title";
$string = json_encode($config);
file_put_contents('config.json', $string);
?>
```

Edit:

same can you do with your $config array in php language:

```
include 'config.php'; // load all $config vars
$config['title'] = "new title";
// now write $config vars to file
```

Comment: While I agree, I'm down-voting because suggesting JSON isn't really within the scope of the question.

Comment: thanks, i added the php variable version too

Comment: As appreciated as that is, it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Of course, but we can also refer to better implementation options here.